# Referencing Objects properly

Tags: java, libgdx

I am creating a simple game, the player basically controls a character that moves left and right avoiding dangerous rocks and trying to catch the different gems to increase their points.

However I am trying to practice my OO design, so I am trying to use an MVC layout.

Here is what I have, hopefully I am doing this wrong since this is the first time doing this without problems :p:

1. I have a GameScreen class which holds all the objects present on the
   screen.
2. I have a WorldRenderer class which handles all animation and
   rendering, as well as the camera.
3. Last but not least, a Controller
   class which handles all input from the user.

Now everything WORKS, the gamescreen creates my objects, my renderer does it job according to my objects states and according to user input. So everything works together just fine.

Example, if I press A the controller changes Jim (the character) to a WALKING STATE and changes a boolean to true if he is facing left, the controller tells the world renderer that A has been pressed, flips the textures and draws them until A is released and moves Jim accordinly, if D is pressed it tells the world renderer to reflip etc etc. If nothing is pressed it sets Jim to an idle state, draws an idle texture.

Now lets check out the code....have a giggle :D:

```
// Draw textures/sprites
    batch.begin();
    if (GameScreen.jim.currentState == 1) {
        if (GameScreen.jim.facingLeft
                && !GameScreen.jim.sprites[1].isFlipX()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameScreen.jim.sprites.length; i++) {
                GameScreen.jim.sprites[i].flip(true, false);
            }
        } else if (!GameScreen.jim.facingLeft
                && GameScreen.jim.sprites[1].isFlipX()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameScreen.jim.sprites.length; i++) {
                GameScreen.jim.sprites[i].flip(true, false);
            }

        }
        batch.draw(GameScreen.jim.currentFrame, GameScreen.jim.bounds.x,
                GameScreen.jim.bounds.y, GameScreen.jim.bounds.getWidth(),
                GameScreen.jim.bounds.getHeight());
    }
    if (GameScreen.jim.currentState == 0) {
        if (GameScreen.jim.facingLeft && !GameScreen.jim.jim0.isFlipX()) {
            GameScreen.jim.jim0.flip(true, false);
        } else if (!GameScreen.jim.facingLeft
                && GameScreen.jim.jim0.isFlipX()) {
            GameScreen.jim.jim0.flip(true, false);
        }
        batch.draw(GameScreen.jim.jim0, GameScreen.jim.bounds.x,
                GameScreen.jim.bounds.y, GameScreen.jim.bounds.getWidth(),
                GameScreen.jim.bounds.getHeight());
    }
    batch.end();
```

Yep, look at the utter nick of that. This works so really, don't fix what is not broken and I will not retouch this code until I have learned more but it's good to know what could be better. I don't like all this stuff:

```
GameScreen.jim.jim0, GameScreen.jim.bounds.x,
                GameScreen.jim.bounds.y,
```

I am constantly having to reference the GameScreen to get to my Jim and then the variables, fields arrays etc in that created Jim.
Not only is this most likely a terrible way to code, it looks utterly horrid :).

Now I was thinking, if I can reference the GameScreen directly how can I not do that for the Jim class and instead just do:

```
Jim.jim0;
```

This throws a null exception because Jim is well, nothing. I haven't created him.

Now if I do this at the top of my class:

```
Jim jim;
```

and then use:

```
jim.jim0;
```

Still null exception.

Should I be using get methods for this? How would I go about avoiding having to referance the GameScreen first before I can get to my created Jim? Is this just not possible?

Sorry for the wall of text, better to have plenty of information and explain what I am after hehe.

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException because you haven't set it to anything.  try `Jim jim = new Jim();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut down on some of the clutter, you can use a static import of the `GameScreen` class.  Assuming it's in the same package:

```
import static GameScreen.*;
```

If it's not in the same package:

```
import static your.package.here.GameScreen.*;
```

Then you can at least reference `jim` directly, e.g.:

```
if (jim.currentState == 1) {
```

This should work, since you state that you have already created the `jim` object.

Comment: Ok that works and makes the code look a little nicer, is there any downsides or problems this method might create?

Comment: The main disadvantage of static imports is the possibility of name collisions between objects that are already in scope and those you're bringing in scope with the static import.  But if it's just for the `jim` object, I think there's no problem with that.  Having multiple static imports can result in confusing code, but if you have just this one class statically imported, then you should be fine.